# How to configure JBoss for applications with libraries declared as provided?

Tags: java, configuration, jboss, war

I have a Java Web application that uses the `OracleConnection` JDBC class to execute some PL/SQL commands. As in our production environment the Oracle driver library is shared by other applications, I need to declare it with a `provided` Maven dependency scope:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
  <artifactId>oracle</artifactId>
  <version>11.2.0.4</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

How should I configure my local **JBoss EAP 6.2** to make this library available for my application? I have tryed to configure it as a core module using `jboss-cli` as described in

[Install a JDBC Driver as a Core Module](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.2/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Install_a_JDBC_Driver_as_a_Core_Module1.html).

This was the last command I have executed:

```
/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=oracle:
add(driver-name=oracle,
driver-module-name=oracle.jdbc,
driver-xa-datasource-class-name=oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource)
```

Commnad output:

```
{"outcome" => "success"}
```

However, at startup our application try to get a connection via DriverManager:

```
OracleConnection conn = (OracleConnection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

This line of code is raising the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.50.240.70:1521:doc21a
```

By other hand, if I change the scope to `compile`, then the Oracle library is deployed along with my application (inside META-INF/lib folder) and everything works fine.

How can I fix this issue? Are core modules proper for this?

Is there another way of sharing libraries with multiple applications using JBoss?

Comment: I am stuck on this problem for a week. I thought this was going to be easy. It seems to be something done ordinarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! As I am using `DriverManager` to get an instance of a vendor specific `Connection` implementation, it is needed to proceed as decribed in the following section of JBoss documentation:

[Access Vendor Specific Classes](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.2/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Access_Vendor_Specific_Classes.html)

Now it is working!